# How to sync the schema change for old document collection in mongodb with default values

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

How can I apply the schema changes to sync with default value to all the old data in mongodb

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

interface ITodo {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  by: string;
}

interface todoModelInterface extends mongoose.Model<TodoDoc> {
  build(attr: ITodo): TodoDoc;
}

interface TodoDoc extends mongoose.Document {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  by: string;
}

const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  by: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

todoSchema.statics.build = (attr: ITodo) => {
  return new Todo(attr);
};

const Todo = mongoose.model<TodoDoc, todoModelInterface>("Todo", todoSchema);

Todo.build({
  title: "some title",
  description: "some description",
  by: "special",
});

Todo.collection.dropIndexes(function () {
  Todo.collection.reIndex(function (finished) {
    console.log("finished re indexing");
  });
});

Todo.collection
  .getIndexes()
  .then((indexes: any) => {
    console.log("indexes:", indexes);
  })
  .catch(console.error);

export { Todo };
```

**Db:**

```
[{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "62cee1eea60e181e412cb0a2"
    },
    "title": "one",
    "description": "one desc"
},{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "62cee2bd44026b1f85464d41"
    },
    "title": "one",
    "description": "one desc",
    "by": "alphs"
},{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "62cee3c8cf1592205dacda3e"
    },
    "title": "one",
    "description": "one desc",
    "by": "alphs"
}]
```

Here the old data still missing the "by" key, similarly if there is nested schema change it may impact the old users, how can we define the default collection for old data in mongodb at runtime without using update query migration?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the default value for "by". By giving a default value, if the old data is missing a value then the default will kick in and return the default value provided. Read about Mongoose Default: [Here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html). I don't know if this is a good practice but we also use this method when there is change in schema and don't want to run update query.

Comment: Yes have added the default, which return the default value in case of missing data on read query, just want to know if there is some way like we have in rdbms orms that sync the database for nay schema change.